# Working with Microsoft Outlook using VBScript

Tags: vbscript, outlook

Trying to automate some things with Microsoft Outlook, but a login prompt is giving me troubles.

```
        Dim objOL, outlook_NS

        Set objOL = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")         
        Set outlook_NS = objOL.GetNamespace("MAPI")

        outlook_NS.Logon "username@email.com", "password", False, True
```

This code here attempts to start Microsoft Outlook, but I get prompted with a Windows Security popup to enter my username and password. I thought the Logon was used for this purpose but it appears it's not. Anyone have any ideas?

I'm trying to log in on a Citrix server, so it's necessary to provide login information as it won't have a Default profile setup.

The prompt looks like this:
[image]

Update: I did some further testing and here's what I believe to be happening, the line

```
    Set objOL = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
```

Doesn't complete execution until we log in with that prompt. With that being said, I don't see a way we are going to be able to accomplish this because the prompt is created from that line of code, but once we hit that line of code we are stuck "in limbo" until either a timeout or we log in.

Comment: Looks like a common problem. Some possible solutions http://kurtsh.com/2012/03/11/howto-prevent-outlook-from-asking-you-for-login-credentials-upon-startup/  and  http://serverfault.com/questions/269373/exchange-2010-and-outlook-2010-requesting-password-every-time-it-starts

Comment: Thanks for the links @niton. I believe that my issue is a bit different however. Because we are logging onto a Citrix server of which we log in as a guest user or normal user I would imagine, the prompt is expected to appear. I just do not see a way to automate the logging in of this prompt.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, Namespace.Logon takes the name of an existing profile, not an email address. One way or another, a profile must be created before you can use Outlook.